# equal areas inside a regular hexagon

Tags: geometry

The figure $ABCDEF$ is a regular hexagon. Find all points $M$ belonging to the hexagon such that

Area of triangle $MAC =$ Area of triangle $MCD$.

Comment: Let the radius be $1$ and the center of the hexagon $(0,0)$.  Take $A = (1, 0), C = (-0.5 , \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) , D = (-1, 0) $.  Express [MAC] and [MCD] , taking $M = (x,y)$.  This will give you an equation of a line in the $xy$ plane.